# io handling in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, io

I noticed a major difference in processing time between two servlets in the same tomcat and two separate tomcats on the same host. The servlets communicate using http. Does tomcat or java have some mechanism that optimizes http communication when in the same tomcat or JVM. I'm trying to confirm this observation is not related to the host I'm running on.

Comment: Nowhere near enough information to know.

Comment: What operating system is this? In the separate JVM scenario are you using the loopback address, or a real interface? (that probably shouldn't matter, but is worth testing while you are at it.) I'm trying to think of a difference in context switches or the efficiency of having just one JVM instead of two competing for resources, but these depend a lot on your workload.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the difference between blocking and non-blocking I/O.

Tomcat uses the multi-thread model: have a pool of threads for processing requests and a queue for incoming requests.  The server assigns a thread to an incoming request for processing, performs the task, sends back the response, and returns the thread to the pool.  The queue handles requests that back up.

Non-blocking IO, as employed by Netty, is something different.

Perhaps the two requests are being queued up when they are processed by the same Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information about these tests. Both tests are run on SunOS 5.10 with Apache Tomcat Version 6.0.20 and jdk1.6.0_23. The http transfers can involve fairly large files - 5M. Thread handling might explain but with timing differences over a factor of 10 makes me suspect that no data has to transfer out of the JVM. Some form of blocking vs non-blocking might fit the timing difference.